# AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'mswindows'

Tags: pyomo

I get the AttributeError when I try to import

```
from coopr.pyomo import *
```

I tried some stuff, using pip (un)install coopr, coopr.pyomo, pyomo, coopr.opt, which wasn't too clever I guess.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Coopr package has been renamed to Pyomo. See [this](http://www.pyomo.org/blog/2015/12/26/updating-to-pyomo-41) blog post for information on how to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. When I run from pyomo.environ import * I get the same error though.
If I run pip install pyomo.environ it tells me that there isn't any version that satisfies my requirements.

Comment: To install the latest version of Pyomo you simply need to run `pip install Pyomo`. However, you need to make sure that any older versions of Pyomo / Coopr (from before the major package restructuring) are uninstalled. The second bullet in that blog post explains how to remove all of the old packages using the pyomo_uninstall.py script.

Comment: I will try that on my work computer first thing tomorrow morning and will let you know if it worked. Sorry I didn't read all the page and thanks for your 2nd hint.

Comment: It "worked"... I don't get the AttributeError but this one...

`RuntimeError: Expression entered generate_expression() with too few references (-1<0); this is indicative of a SERIOUS ERROR in the expression reuse detection scheme.`

( I am wondering: should I close this question and open up a new one, so it's not too confusing for other users having the same problems? ... )

I think my new error might be a version problem (since I read somewhere that Python 3.6 doesn't work with Pyomo right now?)

Comment: Correct, it is a Python 3.6 issue. The issue has been fixed on the development version and will be in the next release. I think the next blog post down on that same page explains how you can install the development version using pip, if you want to go that route.

Comment: It's not that urgent, since my modelling is far from beeing completed I can wait until the update will be released. Anyway, thank's a lot for your support. Happy easter.

Answer (score 0):

python 3.5 rename 'mswindows' to '_mswindows'